# ConcurrentModificationException in Processing

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to implement an `ArrayList` into something I'm making but whenever I to add a new item into the `ArrayList` from within a loop, i get a `ConcurrentModificationError`, which makes sense yet i don't know how to get around this.

My code looks like this:

```
ArrayList<Pipe> pipes;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
  pipes = new ArrayList<Pipe>();
  make();
}
void make() {
  pipes.add(new Pipe());
  Pipe P = pipes.get((pipes.size()-1));
  P.create();
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  for (Pipe p : pipes) {
    p.display();
    p.move();
    if (p.x < 3*width/4) {
      make();
      println("A");
    }  
  }
}
```

The error is definitely not coming from the object it's self and the error occurs when the make() funtion is called within draw().

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You are adding a new `pipe` in `make`, that invalidates the iterator used in the `foreach`

Comment: *Unrelated:* Wouldn't code be better / more obvious / clearer if you wrote `Pipe P = new Pipe(); P.create(); pipes.add(P);` rather than having to do `pipes.get((pipes.size()-1))`

Comment: @Andreas no, i want to make an array of pipes, the code you wrote would make a single pipe, i wouldnt be able to delete the pipe and after a while of new pipes being generated there could be hundreds of invisible and unused pipes.

Comment: @Isac okay, i get that part buit is there a way around it?

Comment: @ThomasAyling I was referring to code inside `make()`, hence the "rather than" reference. How did my suggestion in any way change logic from making an array of pipes to making a single pipe?

Comment: To get around issue: Copy the list before iterating it: `for (Pipe p : new ArrayList<Pipe>(pipes))`

Comment: @Andreas Sorry, i misread and i dont know whyn i didn't write it that way6, it just came to me the way i wrote it, ite makes sense to me i guess it's just how out minds work differently

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) to do the iteration and adding to list.

```
for (ListIterator<Pipe> iter = pipes.listIterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    Pipe p = iter.next();
    [...]
    make(iter);
}
```

And then in make:

`iter.add(new Pipe());`

From the javadoc for `ListIterator`:

> An iterator for lists that allows the programmer to traverse the list in either direction, modify the list during iteration, and obtain the iterator's current position in the list.

Instead of adding to the list, you would be adding to the iterator. There is no concurrent modification in this case since the iterator is able to keep track of list changes.

Note that the `iter.add()` call would add the element just before the element returned by `iter.next()`. This would mean that the newly added object would NOT be the last in the list. This is generally preferable because you don't want to disturb the loop's forward flow i.e. you don't want the next iteration of the loop to be on the newly added object. But your case may vary.

Comment: @MichaelKrause In OPs case the exception is because of modifying the list while iterating over it. It's not a multiple threads situation. For this case, iterator works very well.

Comment: Ah - yes, I saw the comment about calling make() from the draw() function after the fact.  In either case, I believe another option is to use CopyOnWriteArrayList

Comment: I just tested this and the ListIterator returned by ArrayList is fail-fast and does throw a ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: I think I'm just going to use a normal for loop, it's much more simple and doesn't really change much but thanks for the help.

Comment: OK - but you'll run into the same issue.

Comment: @MichaelKrause Not sure what exactly you tried, but here's [proof](https://ideone.com/w5wsHm) that for OP's case my solution works. Did you downvote it?

Comment: Down-voted because this answer has a different outcome, without mentioning the discrepancy. Question code adds all new pipes to the end of the list. Answer code adds new pipes intermingled with the existing content of the list.

Comment: @Andreas How do you conclude that question code adds new pipes to end of list, when its construct isn't even valid i.e. doesn't complete even one addition successfully? Secondly, the main question was about CME, which this answer resolves. And finally, adding new pipe objects to the end means the "current" object pointed to would always be the empty object newly added, and the condition would always fail, which I don't think is the intention.

Comment: @Vasan Because `pipes.add()` adds to the **end** of the list. Question is about how to do the intended logic without incurring `ConcurrentModificationException`. Sure, changing insert location *may* be ok, but changing the intended logic of add-last without mention is bad advice. --- What "condition" would always fail?

Comment: @Vasan Sorry - I see now that you intended the make method signature to change to take a ListIterator param.  It's not clear from the actual code you posted.  Guess the setup() method would also need to be updated in that case.

Comment: @Andreas I've edited my answer to clarify what I meant, which also notes the order behavior.

Comment: @MichaelKrause I had this text in my answer (along with relevant code) right from the start, so no idea what you mean by "it's not clear from the actual code": _Instead of adding to the list, you would be adding to the iterator. There is no concurrent modification in this case since the iterator is able to keep track of list changes._

Comment: *FYI:* There are other ways of doing the intended logic without incurring `ConcurrentModificationException` than changing the logic, e.g. if newly added entries should not be processed, like you mentioned too, then simply iterating a copy of the list would allow adding to end without causing error: `for (Pipe p : new ArrayList<Pipe>(pipes))`

Comment: @Andreas Yup, that's the straightforward way of achieving it, although it does come with the cost of O(n) extra space. I like the iterator way better because it does it in-place.

Comment: @Vasan True, but we're only talking about extra space for the *references*, not the objects themselves, so it's a small hit, usually not of any significance. Your answer is good too, but only if order is unimportant. With the disclaimer of order change you added, the answer is now useful (+1).

Comment: @Vasan All I meant is that it would be clearer if you amended your answer with the actual code for the make method instead of writing prose describing it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) for this.

This will allow mutations to the list while retaining the integrity of the iterator by causing a copy of the underlying array to be made.

This, of course, comes at a performance cost.

Give this a try (I stubbed out methods you call for which you didn't provide an implementation):

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

public class Test {
    private int width;

    private class Pipe {
        public int x;
        public void display() {
        }
        public void move() {
        }
        public void create() {
        }
    }

    List<Pipe> pipes;

    void size(int w, int h) {
    }

    public void background(int i) {
    }

    void setup() {
        size(640, 360);
        pipes = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Pipe>();
        make();
    }

    void make() {
        pipes.add(new Pipe());
        Pipe P = pipes.get((pipes.size() - 1));
        P.create();
    }

    void draw() {
        background(255);
        for (Pipe p : pipes) {
            p.display();
            p.move();
            if (p.x < 3 * width / 4) {
                make();
                System.out.println("A");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.setup();
        t.draw();
    }
}
```

Comment: That will copy the content on *every* insert. Might be better to just copy once at the beginning: `for (Pipe p : new ArrayList<Pipe>(pipes))`. Which is best depends on how many inserts are expected per call to `draw()`, but copy-once has consistent performance, while copy-on-write will have varying performance.

Comment: Agreed.  Probably more performant in most cases to make a copy up front.  But for the sake of illuminating the problem I think using CopyOnWriteArrayList as an example is a bit clearer.